# Save a canvas with border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I've been writing a mini image editor. Upon uploading the to-be-edited image, I draw it into a canvas. One of the editing tools is to add a picture frame, which is taken from several sample images

This is the relating part of my HTML code

```
<div id="canvas-frame">
    <canvas id="edit-canvas" width="500"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="border-tool" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="border-selection active">
        <img src="img/hien/no-border.jpg" id="no-border">
    </div>
    <div class="border-selection">
        <img src="img/hien/border1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="border-selection">
        <img src="img/hien/border2.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript code implementing it

```
        $('#canvas-frame').width($('#edit-canvas').width());
        $('#canvas-frame').height($('#edit-canvas').height());

        function placeBorder(src){
            $('#canvas-frame').css('border-image','url('+src+') 30 round');
            $('#canvas-frame').css('border-width','20px');
        }

        $('#border-tool .border-selection img').click(function(){
            $('#border-tool .border-selection.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            if ($(this).attr('id')=='no-border'){
                $('#canvas-frame').css('border','none');
            } else{
                placeBorder(this.src);
            }
        });
```

As you can see, my idea is to use the `canvas-frame` `div` to wrap around the canvas, then try changing `css` of it. But now I encounter another problem, how to implement a Save button to download the canvas with the bordering frame around it. Could you please give me any suggestions or tutorials to do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll need to draw the borders into the canvas.

Comment: @MikeC Do you have any suggestions? I searched a lot and only managed to find guides about drawing canvas border by line, not by pattern of image. Could you instruct me how to draw canvas border from an image?

Comment: The same way that you draw any image to a canvas. Then you just draw the image along the edges of the canvas and repeat as necessary.

Comment: @MikeC Could you do an example for me? Thank you. I've got confused

Comment: Do you know how to draw an image to a canvas? [It's pretty easy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and information how to do it is all over the internet.

Comment: @MikeC I know how to draw an image to a canvas. As I mentioned above, as soon as I upload the picture to start editing, it is drawn into a canvas. So, yes, I know to draw an image into a canvas. What I don't know is to draw a border, which has pattern from another image, around my existing canvas

Comment: Okay. So you draw your initial image, right? Then you take the image you want to use as a border and draw *that image* onto the canvas. You specify that you only want to draw it along the border instead of on the whole canvas. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @MikeC Thank you very much, I'll try it